# Vertical line centered above div

Tags: html, css

[image: Example]

I am trying to get this done in HTML and CSS. I am able to get the box done using the border and padding. But how do I get the line above?

Here is what I have so far:

```css
.november {
  padding: 1%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="november">November 2014</div>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? post your html and css code here and then people can help you.

Comment: @nikhiln Clearly, OP doesn't know where to start. Everyone has that period of time in anything people do. People who down voted the question **should** comment on what OP can do better.

Comment: @DanielCheung, yeah, seriously. Upvoted and starred because without your question I would not have found the exact solution I needed. Thanks, OP!

Answer (score 6):

### Pseudo element goodness

#### The HTML

It's a one liner:

```
<div>November 2014</div>
```

#### The CSS

The vertical line is created with a [`:before` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before):

- The `:before` pseudo element is given `position: absolute`
- `left: 50%` shifts the line to the middle and `bottom: 100%` pops the line above the div
- The line is created by the 2px width
- `margin-left: -2px` shifts the line 2px to the left to correctly offset its position (this is equal to the width)

The div is made `position: relative` and the `position: absolute` `:before` will position itself in relation to it. Space above the div is created with the top margin.

### Complete Example

In this example, `display: inline-block` allows the div to expand and retract with its contents.

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #000;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div>November 2014</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and got it right:

```css
body {
  background: #EEE;
}
.november {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <hr style="width: 2px; border-top: 50px solid white; padding: 0; text-align: center; margin: auto;" />
  <div class="november">November 2014</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a simpler solution for you in my answer if you like it :)